# How to convert gtsummary object to gt table and/or to tibble table?

Tags: r, tibble, gtsummary, gt, broom

I have got tbl_regression output table which I want to convert to gt() table and then to tibble object if this is possible.
Or directly tbl_regression table into tibble. Is it doable ?

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

set.seed(1000)
my_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2))
) %>% mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))) %>%
mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("Control", "Treatment")))

model3 <- lm(response ~ time * treatment, data = my_data)


gtsummary::tbl_regression(model3,
  pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2),
  estimate_fun = ~ style_number(.x, digits = 4)
) %>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels() -> gts
```

I have tried as follows:

```
gts %>% gtsummary::as_gt() %>% as.data.frame() # not working

# This works a bit, but the output is chaotic:
gts %>%  as_tibble()

gts %>% broom::tidy() %>% as_tibble() # not working
```

There is also a function: as.data.frame.gt_tbl()
https://rdrr.io/cran/gt/man/as.data.frame.gt_tbl.html , but I am not that expert to run it properly.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, how to do it ?

Comment: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/as_tibble.gtsummary.html

Comment: The output looks a bit ugly with all these underscores. It it a way to clean it so it looks more elegant ?

Comment: Well, it's a tibble, not a beautiful table from an engine that draws tables, so best to set expectations low. The underscores are markdown syntax for bold and italicized text. If you don't want them, then remove functions that add that styling

Comment: Which one is it ?

Comment: bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels()